# Browser not downloading request response, even though Content-Disposition is 'attachment' and Content-Type is 'text/plain'

Tags: django, http, pdf, http-headers

I am under the impression that if Content-Disposition is set to 'attachment' and Content-Type is set to'text/plain', the browser should download the request response as a .txt, but when I make the request locally on my browser, a download is not initiated. On other pages, like https://textdoc.co/, my browser does download a similar request response, so it doesn't seem like a browser issue.

On my server:

```
from django.http import FileResponse

...
    with open('readme.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('Create a new text file!')
    response = FileResponse(open("readme.txt", "rb"), as_attachment=True, filename="test.txt")
    response['Content-Type'] = 'application/download'
    return response
```

After making this request on my client I get the following results in the google chrome developer console:

```
**Response Headers:**
Access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:3000
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.txt"
Content-Length: 23
Content-Type: application/download
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Date: Thu, 08 Jun 2023 21:46:37 GMT
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.11.3
Vary: Accept, origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY

**Response:**
Create a new text file!
```

I was expecting this request to cause the browser to prompt the user to download the file. However, the browser is not prompting the user. Here is an example of what the prompt looks like on Google Chrome:

[image: chrome download prompt]